# how to implement Jaccard Similarity in C#

Tags: c#, vector, similarity

I have this problem in calculating Jaccard Similarity for Sets (Bit-Vectors):

v1 = 10111

v2 = 10011

Size of intersection = 3; (How could we find it out?)

Size of union = 4, (How could we find it out?)

Jaccard similarity = (intersection/union) = 3/4

But I don't understand how could we find out the "intersection" and "union" of the two vectors.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your definitions of "intersection" and "union" are "number of bits set in both values" and "number of bits set in either value".... which is (assuming you're using something like `int` or `long` for the vectors):

```
int intersection = CountBits(v1 & v2);
int union = CountBits(v1 | v2);
```

Next you just need to implement `CountBits`. [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) can help you there.

Instead of using `int` or `long`, you may want to use [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). That has `And` and `Or` methods, which *look* like they don't mutate the original values, but it's not entirely clear. You'd need to work out the best way of counting the bits set in a `BitArray` of course - just `array.Cast<bool>().Count(bit => bit)` may well work.

Comment: I've saved bits in an array , How do I convert it to a vector

Comment: @AML: Well you don't need to - you can just count the bits which are present in both arrays, or present in either. Without any more information about how you're representing anything, it's very hard to help you further. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints